# npm install --save, what is the use of not saving

Tags: node.js, npm

I understand the differences between `npm install something` and `npm install something --save` (for anyone wondering, the first one will install the dependency only while the latter will install the dependency and add it to your package.json).

However I do not understand why there is a `--save` option in the first place. In other words, why would you ever want to install a dependency **without** adding it to your package.json file? Why is the --save option not default?

A lot of websites/npm modules/SaaS suggest installing their module using `npm install something` (newrelic is one of them for instance), am I missing something?

**Edit**: [Starting from NPM 5](https://medium.com/@treyhuffine/whats-new-in-node-8-e1cce6539a71), `--save` is now on by default.

Comment: If you are installing some debugging tools for instance, say `nodemon`, you'd not want it in your package.json

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. You would have a scenario such as you need some module to install without adding dependency to `package.json` file, for ex. you just want to try some module, and not sure you would be really using that module in production or while deploying, so instead adding the module dependency to `package.json`, just give it a try without using `--save`. this is why `npm install` without `--save` exists.
2. But For most of your modules you might require using `--save`, for ex. `npm install express --save`,
   in this case you surely know that you are going to use express for you application.
3. The other scenario, for not using `--save`, would be, `npm install heapdump` or `npm install nodemon`, I would use it for testing my apps performance, but not add a dependency in the package.json :)
4. Also, As @surajck said in comment below: when you are doing global installs, in that case adding dependencies using `--save`, to the `package.json` would not make sense.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier/better to always use `--save` and run [depcheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck) before comitting/deploying?

Comment: well, as depcheck page on npm says, **But that's a hassle too.**

Comment: @Nepoxx what about when you are doing global installs, in that case adding it to the package.json would not make sense.

Comment: exellent @surajck.. shall I add your opinion to my answer.

Comment: @surajck But then you need the `-g` flag.

Comment: @Nepoxx. But then It makes no sense, if you still use `--save` with `-g`

Comment: Yes, so you are also suggesting that, if there is a `-g` flag, then override the auto `--save` feature?

Comment: Your answer/comments explained very well why it is not so, but for the sake of argument, I **think** it would make sense to have `--save` by default (and therefore providing a `--nosave` option). So,  `npm install something` would install something and save it, `npm install something -g` would install it globally (therefore not save it, since it would make no sense) and `npm install something --nosave` would install the dependency and not save it. In the end, it ends up being the same, I'm just not sure which one is more straightforward.

Comment: Yes that would be really nice.. But we dont have it yet.. :)

Comment: I completely agree with @Nepoxx. This discussion deserves to go further in a github issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12031

Answer (score 12):

I just learned a nice trick from Jonathan Mills' *JavaScript Best Practices* course on Pluralsight. From the terminal:
`npm config set save=true`
Now I don't need to remember `--save` anymore. And I also now use
`npm config set save-exact=true`
Because I want the exact version of the package not the `^` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

By default with version npm 5.0+ npm install adds the module to the dependencies list in the package.json file; with earlier versions of npm, you must specify the `--save` option explicitly. Then, afterwards, running npm install in the app directory will automatically install modules in the dependencies list.