# How to install a package through npm without setting up package.json

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276345/npm-save-installed-packages-as-dependencies) post it is possible to install npm packages first and then create **package.json** later on.

I have installed nodeJS in my computer. In an empty folder, when I run below command:

```
npm install jQuery
```

It gives below error on console:

> D:\Rasik\reactJs\learnJs
> `-- jquery@3.2.1
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'D:\Rasik\reactJs\learnJs\package.json'
> npm WARN learnJs No description
> npm WARN learnJs No repository field.
> npm WARN learnJs No README data
> npm WARN learnJs No license field.

I'm working on an HTML Vanilla JavaScript (JS) project. I want to use npm to get latest packages or the JS files. I don't want to do **npm init** before installing the packages as this is not some ReactJS kind of application.

Comment: Those are not errors but warnings. A folder `node_modules` should be present and the package should be downloaded without issue.

Comment: ohhh...my bad. I didn't even look into the root directory after seeing so many logs on the command shell. Sorry to bother you. Thanks.

Comment: You can refer https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json for info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a mistake from my end as I didn't notice **node_modules** directory. There is no additional effort or prerequisite involved in installing or uninstalling a package through NPM. Any node package can be installed even without having **package.json** file in your root directory (which is created through **npm init** command).

Running **npm install jQuery** results in installation of jQuery module. It creates **\node_modules\jquery** directory in root with all the relevant files.

Additionally, package name for npm install command is case insensitive so all following commands are equivalent:

```
npm install jquery
npm install jQuery
npm install jQuErY
```

Answer (score 3):

You can install npm packages without package.json by just running `npm install <package name>`, but it is not recommended. Since if you want to push it to Github or so, uploading the entire node modules is going to be a pain.

It is very easy to set up a package.json file. You just have to run `npm init` and press enter key a few times which would use default values, or you can edit the author and keywords and all.

If you're too lazy, just do `npm init -y` which will initialise package.json with default values

A package.json file is very useful because if you have to share your code, it is very hard without a package.json file since you'll have to copy all folders in node_modules. If you have a package.json, all you have to do is run `npm install`, which will download all packages on its own

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried running `npm config get save` to check if the --save value is set to true/false?

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821909/npm-install-save-what-is-the-use-of-not-saving) topic.