# why does serverless framework not include package.json for aws-nodejs template

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverless-framework

When trying to create a new serverless project using the cli

```
sls create -t aws-nodejs -p testfolder
```

Serverless framework creates:

1. handler.js
2. serverless.yml
3. .gitignore

Why doesn't a package.json be included and also why is only a package-lock.json file created / generated when installing npm packages e.g lodash

Running the following:

```
npm install --save lodash
```

only creates a node_module folder and a package-lock.json file. There is no package.json file. Trying to understand why as this is not the case with:

```
sls create -t aws-nodejs-typescript -p test
```

```
nvm: 0.39.1
node: v14.19.3
npm: 6.14.17

sls

Framework Core: 3.21.0
Plugin: 6.2.2
SDK: 4.3.2
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: before nstalling lodash you need to manually initiate `npm init -y` after that install ur dependancies

Comment: for your second question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322366/how-to-install-a-package-through-npm-without-setting-up-package-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the framework probably could create a `package.json` for you when you create a new nodejs project. However, there are several cases where a user wouldn't need any node modules at all, so it makes sense to not provide a `package.json` file unless the user installs other dependencies.

The typescript template is a bit different, because the Serverless Framework has a plugin system which is based on [npm](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/bf79934e9b43a0b2e8613ee29f9430fa22c41481/commands/plugin-install.js#L48-L51), so adding a plugin will require a `package.json` file to track the dependency.

So when you run `sls create -t aws-nodejs-typescript`, it automatically generates a `serverless.yml` file which includes the `serverless-esbuild` plugin, and thus creates a `package.json` file tracking it. The typescript template also includes a bunch of dev dependencies, which also are tracked via npm.